# Can I store a key in Redis that is a promise?

Tags: javascript, redis, promise

I want to store 'pair' in Redis. After spending 10 hours searching and testing I just could not make it work. Pls help. 'pair' is a promise!

.then(pair => console.log(pair))

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Have you though about storing the value *after* the promise has been fulfilled? Please include some more code related to your question for context.

Comment: how would I store it? It remains a promise if I got it right

Comment: Like I asked, please include the rest of the code. This is too little to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok since this question is getting some traffic I show you my solution: Move the promise into a .json (stringyfied), and then import the string from the .json.
That works for me.